# Workspace optional dependencies (std & no_std)

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am developing a code for my school's rocketry team and I have two programs, one meant to flash the on-board computer and another to run some data analysis on the flight data. The chip code uses `no_std` while the data analysis program uses `std`. The `data-analysis` code will run on my PC, and the `chip` code will run on the chip.
Here is my workspace root `Cargo.toml` and my project graph:

```
[workspace]

members = [
    "chip",
    "data-analysis",
]
```

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── chip
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   ├── memory.x
│   ├── openocd.cfg
│   ├── openocd.gdb
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
├── data-analysis
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
├── README.md
└── resources
    ├── 3m.mkd
    ├── data-stm32f103c8t6.pdf
    ├── links.txt
    ├── reference-stm32f103xx.pdf
    ├── schematic-stm32f103c8t6.png
    └── todo.txt
```

I have decided to use a workspace to organize my code. When I attempt to build the workspace, I get the error:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
  |
  = note: the `thumbv7m-none-eabi` target may not support the standard library
  = note: `std` is required by `data_analysis` because it does not declare `#![no_std]`
  = help: consider building the standard library from source with `cargo build -Zbuild-std`
```

When I compile with `cargo build -Zbuild-std` I get the error:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `panic_abort`

error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'restricted_std'
  |
  = help: add `#![feature(restricted_std)]` to the crate attributes to enable
```

However I need `no_std` and not `restricted_std`.

I understand that dependencies for all files are stored in `Cargo.lock` and presumably that's why it is producing this error. My question is, how do I express to the compiler that I need `std` for `data_analysis` but not for `chip` code? Should I even be using workspaces over just using one package with multiple binaries and using `[features]` in the `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: Is the data analysis code supposed to run on the same CPU as the "chip" code, or is the data analysis supposed to run on your PC?

Comment: @Jmb on my pc, sorry, I will clarify that.

Comment: AFAIK each cargo run can only target a single platform, so either your PC or the embedded chip. Since `chip` and `data-analysis` are compiled for different targets, they can't be compiled simultaneously, you'll have to make them into independent projects.

Comment: My goal is to keep them in one project, with that being said, would you recommend just having a project with multiple binaries and expressing their targets in a `config.toml`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to complile `data_analysis` with the same target as `chip`. I recommend just getting rid of the root Cargo.toml and compiling the respective ones in the folders. You could make a Makefile to automate this easily